# Error Inflating Class Fragment ... none of previous are helpful .. don't know the error

Tags: android

**This is ERROR**

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3637)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.lenovo.ridder.Home.onCreate(Home.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

**This is Home Code**

```
package com.example.lenovo.ridder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(30.677717,-73.106812))
                .title("S A H I W A L"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(30.677717,-73.106812),12));

    }
}
```

**The Error is in this line**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

**And this is home_activity.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I had looked to all previous issues related to this error but can't solve the error please help me in this ... Thanks in advance

I have uploaded the code and mention the where it is location the error in it Now don't know how to solve this

**App_bar_home code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_location"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <view
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="@color/dividerColor"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_destination"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: share app_bar_home code

Comment: I have edited it please check

Answer (score 0):

Your `<fragment>` tags are missing their `android:name` attribute. This is what tells the inflater which Fragment class to use.

It looks like you've maybe accidentally put this attribute on an earlier `<ImageView>` tag instead.

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_black_24dp"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
>
> <fragment
>     android:id="@+id/place_location"
>     android:layout_weight="5"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
> ```

If I'm right, you'd want this instead:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_black_24dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_location"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
```

Comment: Brother Now this error is showing 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: That's certainly a different error. The best thing to do would be to find the exact location in the code where that happens and open another question if you can't figure out how the `NullPointerException` is happening.

Comment: Now what can I do for this ?

Comment: This is solved. If you've gotten beyond the layout inflating, you now have a completely separate issue.

Comment: Yeah this is solved but Can you help me in Other problem? and can you tell me your email please